# Given a specific rational number, is there a way to find an n and k for the binomial coefficient that will evaluate to it?

Tags: combinatorics

Looking at Pascal's triangle, it looks as though all rational numbers can also be expressed as binomial coefficients. Given a rational integer, is it possible to calculate n & k for the binomial coefficient that will evaluate to it?

Comment: Rational integer???

Comment: ${n\choose 1} = n$ for all integers $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Yup, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks